# oracle sql -not matter upper or lower in cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor, uppercase, lowercase

enter a domain name to search on the database, no matter the domain name is upper or lower, as long as the alpha is matching.

example.  'hotmail.com' in the database,  If I enter 'hOTmAIL.Com'. it still found the domain name 'hotmail.com'.

```
cursor E_info is select Email_Address from broker
where REGEXP_LIKE (substr(Email_Address, instr(Email_Address,'@')+1), old_email);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without using regexp_like.

> Lower

```
select * from test where lower(substr(email_address,instr(email_address,'@')+1))=lower('HotMail.com');
```

This will return the results faster as compared to regexp_like as you are doing exact match.

EDIT

```
create or replace procedure PR_Q3
(old_email in varchar2, new_email in varchar2)
authid current_user
is 
cursor E_info is select Email_Address from test where lower(substr(email_address,instr(email_address,'@')+1))=lower(old_email);
v_email E_info%rowtype;
begin 
open E_info;
loop
fetch E_info into v_email;
exit when E_info%notfound;
update test set 
Email_Address = replace(Email_Address,substr(Email_Address,instr(Email_Address,'@')+1),new_email) 
where Email_Address = v_email.Email_Address;
end loop;
close E_info;
end PR_Q3;
/
```

Comment: you can replace the value with variable.

Comment: `If I enter 'hOTmAIL.Com'` means where will you enter?

Comment: using a procedure

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure PR_Q3
(old_email in varchar2, new_email in varchar2)
authid current_user
is 
cursor E_info is select Email_Address from broker
where REGEXP_LIKE (substr(Email_Address, instr(Email_Address,'@')+1), old_email);
v_email E_info%rowtype;
begin 
open E_info;
loop
fetch E_info into v_email;
exit when E_info%notfound;
update broker set 
Email_Address = replace(Email_Address,substr(Email_Address,instr(Email_Address,'@')+1),new_email) 
where Email_Address = v_email.Email_Address;
end loop;
close E_info;
end PR_Q3;
```